# Monero GUI not recognising my Ledger X anymore...how can I get it to remember?

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, daemon, hard-fork, wallet-recovery, ledger

I set up my Ledger X successfully back in May 2020 and decided against setting up a password for simplicity's sake. I recently updated to the new MUI 0.17.1.4 - Oxygen Orion in preparation for the recent upgrade to the network. When I tried again, this error message appeared for which as a crypto novice, I have no idea what to do!

Foolishly, although I have a backup of the keys file I did not note my private or public keys that are needed to restore the device. I have my ledger, the GUI and the keys files. Could anyone offer pointers to what troubleshooting measures I can take to find my way back to wallet heaven? :)

[image: Error screen message of dread!]

Comment: Please try updating your firmware as well as the Ledger Monero App. Let us know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You should not worry for your assets. Those are kept safely on wallet created from private keys kept on your ledger device. So as long as you have access to your ledger and its seed/pin/passphrase it should be all fine. In your case, restoring the wallet should make it work again. Open Monero GUI App and close any wallet which is opened by default. Choose an option to make a new wallet: "Create a new wallet from hardware". Then you should go with option "Restore a wallet from device". After creation and some wallet syncing is done you should be able to access your assets again. Let us know how it went.